# Using Git and two local folders on the same Windows 7computer

Tags: git, windows-7

I attempting to learn Git (Git version 1.9.4.msysgit.2) on a Windows 7 laptop.

I would like to create a `source` folder and a `code` folder to practice on.

I can create a master folder using `git init` and add the test file using `git add .` and `git commit -m "original file"`.

Then in the `code` folder I use `git clone c:\source\` Git warns:

```
You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
```

and calls the folder (master).  `git add .` and `git commit` works fine when I add a test file.  But when I `git push` to what I consider to be the master repository Git reports the following:

```
$ git push
fatal: 'c:source' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I am finding references on how to clone to and from remote repositories but I would like to understand how to achieve local folder transactions first.  Is it possible or what part of my logic is flawed?

Comment: If you're using Git Bash (or some other POSIXy environment) you might have to escape or quote those backslashes, e.g: `git clone c:\\source\\ ` or `git clone 'c:\source\'`.

Comment: The git clone is working as I outlined.  My problem is that I need a solution to the `git push` error.  Or can I `push` from one local folder to another, is ths possible? Or I'm just barking mad?  ;-)

Comment: Pushing from a repository in a local directory to another repository in a local directory is just fine. What looks odd to me is when Git mentions `c:source` (without the backslash) when pushing. Also the warning about an empty repository is odd. What do `git status` and `git whatchanged` show in the ‘master‘ repository? (Please stop calling directories and repositories ‘master’ by the way, since it has ‘special meaning’ in Git.)

Comment: Try the msysgit version of the pathname:  `git clone /c/source`.